# Minecraft: Prevent snow from accumulating around

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Here is my house:
[image: Pretty house]

Now it looks good right? But what is not good is the snow on my road/walkway.

I would like to prevent snow from spawning when it is snowing. I like the snowing atmosphere so I usually keep it on. I do not want to use a lot of light and I would not want the whole world to stop spawning snow. Just the road.

How do I do this? I am fine with using commands.

Comment: If you don't insist on cobblestone blocks for the road you can use actual path blocks or cobblestone slabs - snow only forms on top of full blocks

Comment: Worldguard: `snow-fall: deny` (keeps snowing, but prevents snow from spawning on the ground)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the road out of half slabs. This should prevent the snow from settling.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could add roof over your road. So it loks more like walkway. Support the roof with fences as if they were preventing the roof from falling